# Backslash preceding whitespaces and newline splice

Tags: c, language-lawyer

The `N2310/5.1.1.2(p1)` defines translation phases. Particularly the phase 2:

> 2. Each instance of a backslash character ( `\` ) immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to
>      form logical source lines. Only the last backslash on any physical
>      source line shall be eligible for being part of such a splice. A
>      source file that is not empty shall end in a new-line character, which
>      shall not be immediately preceded by a backslash character before any
>      such splicing takes place.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    //There are spaces after the backslash before the new-line
    int i = 12\                  
34;
printf("%d\n", i); //prints 1234
}
```

On my machine it compiles with `gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0` with a

```
warning: backslash and newline separated by space
     int i = 12\
```

But prints `1234` anyway.

Is this a `gcc`/`clang` non-standardized extension and fully conforming compiler should print error in such case even without `-Werror` flag?

Comment: I found a closely related issue recently, in the context of testing CRLF line endings (they're allowed through after the backslash, even if the rest of the file does not use CRLF line endings). In my view, it is GCC breaking the literal wording of the standard — but it makes a program compile that otherwise would not, with no harm done. The alternative is that the program is rejected. With spaces instead of CR, or with multiple CR before the LF, I get errors or warnings. It is mostly GCC being kind. I'm not sure it's really a good idea, but a diagnostic is emitted which satisfies the standard.

Comment: Since I routinely compile with `-Werror`, it doesn't affect me much.  On the very rare occasions when I have a macro that needs continuing (I can think of no other context where a backslash-newline is needed — big string literals are best created by string concatenation, not by using backslash-newline), if that error (because I use `-Werror`; warning if you don't) appeared, I'd fix it before I got to run the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard does not differentiate between warnings and errors, it just uses one term "diagnostic message." A conforming compiler must issue a diagnostic message when it encounters an invalid program. However, it is not required to terminate compilation at that point. C11 (N1570) 5.1.1.3 says this explicitly:

> A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message (identified in
>   an implementation-defined manner) if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit
>   contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the behavior is also explicitly
>   specified as undefined or implementation-defined. Diagnostic messages need not be
>   produced in other circumstances.<sup>9)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> 9) The intent is that an implementation should identify the nature of, and where possible localize, each
>   violation. Of course, **an implementation** is free to produce any number of diagnostics as long as a
>   valid program is still correctly translated. It **may also successfully translate an invalid program**.

(Emphasis mine)

This means that gcc is fully conforming when it issues a warning and then translates the code in any way it sees fit. This is really just a usability feature.